How to perform socket operation on a worker thread in Javascript?
I am trying to implement WebRTC signaling using socket.io. Since handling new connections and handling different events for signaling will take a huge toll if performed on a single thread, I am thinking of using a worker thread for handling all socket.io's operations.
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

const fs = require("fs");

const Random = require("./random.cjs")

const { Worker } = require('worker_threads')


console.log(path.join(__dirname, "../public"));
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


// Express Middleware for serving static files
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../client")));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/client1.html'));
});

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/client1.html'));
});


thread = new Worker("./general_thread.js");   // worker thread for handling socket io operations                


var users = 0;
var roomCount = 1;

io.on('connection', (socket) => {        // code which I need to run on worker thread
  console.log('a user connected');

  socket.join("room" + roomCount);
  users++;

  console.log("--------------" + Random.getString())
  if (users == 1) {
    users++;
    io.to(Array.from(socket.rooms)[1]).emit("becomeClient1");
  } else {
    users = 0;
    roomCount++; // assuming roomCount won't overflow
    socket.emit("becomeClient2");
    io.to(Array.from(socket.rooms)[1]).emit("notifyClient1");
  }

  socket.on("client1offer", (client1offer) => {
    console.log("cl1 offer--------" + JSON.stringify(client1offer));
    socket.broadcast.to(Array.from(socket.rooms)[1]).emit("client1offer", client1offer);
  });

  socket.on("client1IceCandidates", (client1iceCandidate) => {
    console.log("ice--------" + client1iceCandidate);
    socket.broadcast.to(Array.from(socket.rooms)[1]).emit("client1IceCandidates", client1iceCandidate);
  });

  socket.on("client2answer", answer => {
    console.log("cl2 answer emit");
    socket.broadcast.to(Array.from(socket.rooms)[1]).emit("client2answer", answer);
  });

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log("----socket close----------");
  });
});




server.listen(8082, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:8082');
});


Please let me know how should I approach the problem and how can we share the http connection objects between multiple threads?
I am not sure if what I am trying to do is possible/correct way to approach.
Thank you.

You don't want to use worker threads for socket IO, you won't gain any performance.  Worker threads are when you have something blocking & taking a long time.  eg.  If your socket implementation had a function to work out PI to thousands of digits, you would put that in the worker thread not the actual socket IO connection.
